# Blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a point has Picard group $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ at $P=(0:0:1)$ and $\pi:X\to\mathbb{P}^2$ the projection map. I'm trying to prove that:

> $\text{Pic}(X)\simeq \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

Here is my attempt. Define the map:

\begin{align*}
\text{Div}(X)&\to\text{Div}(\mathbb{P}^2)\\
E&\mapsto 0\\
D\neq E&\mapsto \pi(D)
\end{align*}

which induces a map $\varphi:\text{Pic}(X)\to\text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^2)$. We then have an exact sequence:
$$\mathbb{Z}\to\text{Pic}(X)\to\text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^2)\to 0$$

where the first map is given by $1\mapsto [E]$. Clearly the map $\pi^*:\text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^2)\to\text{Pic}(X)$ gives a right split in the sequence.

Knowing that $\text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^2)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and using the splitting lemma, the only thing left to prove is that the map $1\mapsto[E]$ is injective.

I'm stuck here. If $m[E]=0$ for some $m\geq 1$, then $mE=\text{div}(f)$ for some $f\in k(X)$. The problem is that I don't know how to actually write down rational functions in $X$.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you assume WOLG that $E$ is the point $[0, 0, 1]$, then there is an explicit description of $X$ as $\operatorname{Proj}k[x, y, z, w]/(xz - yw)$, where $x, y$ have degree $0$ and $z, w$ have degree $1$.

Comment: You haven't managed to compute $E^2 = -1$ yet have you? (I don't recall if this requires knowing $\operatorname{Pic}$ on the nose). Because them $(mE)^2 = -m^2 \neq 0$ which should be enough to distinguish $mE$ from the trivial class.

Comment: @TabesBridges this does work, but may be a little bomb-as-flyswatter for some folk's tastes. I've included some discussion in my answer.

Comment: @TabesBridges, by the way, your argument would work for any $D$ with $D^2\neq 0$, right? I mean, we would have $(mD)^2=m^2D^2\neq 0$, which would give $[mD]\neq 0$.

Comment: @rmdmc89 Yes, of course. You can prove any divisor class is nonzero by showing that it has some kind of non-zero behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we note that $\Bbb P^2$ and $X$ are birational: the open sets $\Bbb P^2\setminus P$ and $X\setminus E$ are isomorphic (the blowup map actually restricts to the identity here). This means that the function fields are isomorphic, and a function $f$ which has $div(f)=E$ on $X$ would necessarily have $div(f)=P$ on $\Bbb P^2$, which is obviously impossible. So $E\neq 0$ in the Picard group.

Tabes Bridges' comment is also a possible approach to the problem, as the self-intersection number can be computed only by knowing the degree of the normal bundle (without assuming anything about the class of $E$). As the exceptional divisor $E$ of a blowup in a point of a smooth variety of dimension $n$ has normal bundle $\mathcal{O}_E(E) \cong \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^{n-1}}(-1)$ (this is standard when defining the blowup and does not require knowledge of the Picard group of the blowup), we see that the self-intersection number of the exceptional divisor is $(-1)^{n-1}$. So if one can demonstrate that the intersection product is a well-defined thing on the Picard group, this would suffice to show that $E\neq 0$.

Comment: in deed I missed the fact that $X$ and $\mathbb{P}^2$ are birrationally equivalent. But instead of arguing that $\text{div}(f)=P$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ like you did, would it make sense to say that if $\text{div}(f)=E$ on $X$ then $f$ as a function on $\mathbb{P}^2$ would have no poles (which is impossible in $\mathbb{P}^2$)?

Comment: I think that's essentially the same argument and should also work.

Comment: KReiser, is it correct to say moreover that a rational function $f\in k(X)$ cannot have a zero nor a pole at $E$? Otherwise, I don't see how this zero or pole would translate via the isomorphism $k(X)\simeq k(\Bbb{P}^2)$

Comment: The isomorphism $k(X)\cong k(\Bbb P^2)$ is via pullback along $X\to \Bbb P^2$, which should tell you everything you need to know here. The point is that the pullback of a rational function $f$ defined at the point $p$ you're blowing up takes the same value along all of $E$: $f(p)$. So certainly you could have the function give $0$ or $\infty$ on $E$: for instance, blowing up $[0:0:1]$, you could choose $x_0/x_2$ or $x_2/x_0$ as a function with a zero or pole respectively - the thing here is that it can't be the case that $f$ has a zero or pole only along $p$ (equivalently only along $E$).

Comment: just one last question: I'm trying to mimic this proof for a general blowup of $b:\widetilde{S}\to S$ of a nonsingular projective surface $S$ at $P$. How do we prove $n[E]=0$ implies $n=0$ in this case? In $\Bbb{P}^2$ it's clear that if $f$ has a zero it must have at least one pole, but what about in $S$?

Comment: @rmdmc89 The key feature here is that zero/pole sets of rational functions are codimension one, so no set of codimension two or more can be the whole zero/pole locus.